# SSRS and SharePoint 2010

Tags: reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, ssrs-2008

I have use SSRS 2008 before installing SharePoint 2010. I dig around that there is a way to switch the mode from native to sharepoint integration but the question now is when i did my swicth did all my reports in native mode are gone? need to be rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was exactly looking for the same thing.

Apparently you need to create a new database in integrated mode, and then upload all your reports (you can script this task). I think it's also needed to then manually recreate subscriptions and any other configurations....

for more detils:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/sqlreportingservices/thread/942e72b6-a9c5-4874-8d68-8b658e8705b5